# Copying contract products in a plugin - Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I am writing a plugin that copies the contract products from a contract to a newly created opportunity. It seems to copy existing products fine, but if there are any write-in products something goes wrong. The write-in opportunity product appears to be copied correctly but when I try and open it I get a message saying that an error has occurred. The plugin seems to complete successfully.

Anyone got any ideas what might be happening?

Here's the code:

```
//Operate on each contract product found 
foreach (var contProd in contProdCollection.Entities)
{

    //Create the new opp product
    Entity newOppProd = new Entity("opportunityproduct");

    //Get comm rate from the old connection
    ColumnSet contProdCols = new ColumnSet("isproductoverridden", "productid", "uomid", "ispriceoverridden", "quantity", "priceperunit", "extendedamount", "new_costperunit", "new_totalcost");
    Guid contProdId = contProd.Id;
    Entity contProd2 = service.Retrieve("quotedetail", contProdId, contProdCols);

    newOppProd.Attributes["opportunityid"] = newOpp;

    //check whether the product is a write in or not

    if (contProd2.GetAttributeValue<Boolean>("isproductoverridden") == false)
    {
        //product is existing
        //fill in the details of the new opp product

        newOppProd.Attributes["isproductoverridden"] = contProd2.Attributes["isproductoverridden"];

        if (contProd2.Contains("productid") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["productid"] = contProd2.Attributes["productid"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("uomid") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["uomid"] = contProd2.Attributes["uomid"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("ispriceoverridden") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["ispriceoverridden"] = contProd2.Attributes["ispriceoverridden"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("quantity") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["quantity"] = contProd2.Attributes["quantity"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("priceperunit") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["priceperunit"] = contProd2.Attributes["priceperunit"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("extendedamount") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["extendedamount"] = contProd2.Attributes["extendedamount"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("new_costperunit") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["new_customerrate"] = contProd2.Attributes["new_costperunit"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("new_totalcost") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["new_customercost"] = contProd2.Attributes["new_totalcost"];
        }
        service.Create(newOppProd);

    }
    else
    {
        //product is write in
        newOppProd.Attributes["isproductoverridden"] = contProd2.Attributes["isproductoverridden"];

        if (contProd2.Contains("productdescription") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["productdescription"] = contProd2.Attributes["productdescription"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("ispriceoverridden") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["ispriceoverridden"] = contProd2.Attributes["ispriceoverridden"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("quantity") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["quantity"] = contProd2.Attributes["quantity"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("priceperunit") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["priceperunit"] = contProd2.Attributes["priceperunit"];
        }
        //if (contProd2.Contains("extendedamount") == true)
        //{
        //    newOppProd.Attributes["extendedamount"] = contProd2.Attributes["extendedamount"];
        //}
        if (contProd2.Contains("new_costperunit") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["new_customerrate"] = contProd2.Attributes["new_costperunit"];
        }
        if (contProd2.Contains("new_totalcost") == true)
        {
            newOppProd.Attributes["new_customercost"] = contProd2.Attributes["new_totalcost"];
        }
             service.Create(newOppProd);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code.  What is your error you're getting?  And you say you're getting it when you're attempting to navigate to the newly created Opportunity Product in CRM?  It sound to me like most likely be a javascript error or a select plugin error.

Comment: @Daryl It just gives a generic "Microsoft Dynamics CRM has encountered an error" message. Nothing more useful than that. And yes, it occurs when trying to view the new Opportunity Product

Comment: No Download File Option?

Comment: Do you have any Javascript that runs in the OnLoad?  Maybe expecting a ProductId to be populated?